# How to tell high-quality food from the rest in a stockpile?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I need to feed noble and soldiers with the finest food in the fortress and give leftovers to peasants (I peeped at government to learn this trick).

But it turned out that stockpile does not allow one to set quality food in settings. Is there other way of doing that?

Comment: You can check the food quality individually with the "look" tool - I doubt that's what you meant, though.  I usually rely on ALL of my  prepared meals becoming masterwork after a certain point (and sell the lowest-quality meals to each caravan).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about it. If you keep the same cooks making meals eventually the vast majority of them will be masterwork. Sell the lower quality meals to caravans.

Comment: I would also like to add the following: Whenever possible, dwarves will tend to choose the highest quality food available to them, even if its in the bottom of the mines.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard: that is why you forbid all food items except the ones you want them to eat. "You have your choice of thee kinds of dried up plump helmets." "Oh, that nice food over there? you aren't allowed to eat that, we will be selling that to the next caravan. Sorry."